# NSPredicate to filter out vars

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nspredicate

I have links like this www.somestuff.com/index.php?getsome=1:someInt:3

Is it possible to filter out the 1 and the 3 using NSPredicate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think NSPredicate will help you here. How about:

```
NSString *url = @"www.somestuff.com/index.php?getsome=1:someInt:3";
NSArray *parameters = [url componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
NSInteger first = [[parameters objectAtIndex:0] intValue];  // 1
NSInteger second = [[parameters objectAtIndex:2] intValue]; // 3
```

You see that I am making some assumptions about the structure of the url, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184845/how-to-get-matches-in-ios-using-regular-expression), using NSRegularExpression that might be usefull to someone