# Simple (tutorial/blog/explanation) of basic RegEx implementation(searching for a string in another string) in Cocoa XCode?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsregularexpression

I have an html code stored in a string. Now I want to extract one of the images from the source code.

I was earlier using REgExKitLite but according to this link http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/288966-applications-using-regexkitlite-no-longer-being-accepted-at-the-appstore.html , it's suggested not to use REgExKitLite if we want to submit my app to app store.

I just need a very simple implementation to extract one string from another using regEx. Most of the other SO solutions are trying to achieve pretty complex tasks and hence its difficult to understand for a beginner like me.

Even a good tutorial link(about NSRegularExpression implementation) will do. I really dont mind reading it and learning the basics as long as the tutorial is simple and clear. Thnx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In iOS 4.0+, you can use **NSRegularExpression**:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"stack(.*).html" options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *str = @"stackoverflow.html";
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:str options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
// [match rangeAtIndex:1] gives the range of the group in parentheses
// [str substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]] gives the first captured group in this example
```

You can follow this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184845/how-to-get-matches-in-ios-using-regular-expression) to get more solutions.