# iPhone:How to fetch special characters from an array

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

Suppose I have an array as follows:

```
shuffleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"H",@"$",@"E",@"*",@"L",@"L",@"O", nil];
```

I want to fetch only special characters from this array

and in addition after fetching them I want to remove these special characters from array

How can I do it?

Any Help will be appreciable.

Thanx in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Try this out,

```
NSMutableArray *shuffleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"H",@"$",@"E",@"*",@"L",@"L",@"O", nil];
    NSLog(@"Letters Array%@",[shuffleArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *evaluatedString, NSDictionary *bindings) {
              return [[evaluatedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]] length]==0;

    }]]); 
    NSLog(@"Special Characters  Array%@",[shuffleArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSString *evaluatedString, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [[evaluatedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]] length]!=0;

    }]]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *shuffleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"H",@"$",@"E",@"*",@"L",@"L",@"O", nil];
for(int i=0; i<[shuffleArray count];i++)
{
    unichar c = [[shuffleArray objectAtIndex:i] characterAtIndex:0];
    if (![[NSCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet] characterIsMember:c])
    {
        NSLog(@"%c",c);
        [shuffleArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
        i--;
    }
}
```

tried this and it works. hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think it is right to modify the array while traversing through it.

Comment: user says he wants to " I want to remove these special characters from array"

Comment: @AnshukGarg, Xcool is talking about good practice. It has got nothing to do with requirement.

Comment: @vignesh : he explicitly asked to remove them, so let the user clarify. :)

Comment: @XCool : can u explain a li'l in brief. thnx

Comment: @AnshukGarg. Let removing be the requirement. But removing item from an array while you iterate it is wrong. It is not about requirement.

Comment: @AnshukGarg you can try that code out to see it for yourself ;)

Comment: @XCool : i tried it and it works fine on my side, thts y i posted it.

Comment: Yes, it works for the set of data provided, but will it work for a different set of data? Try it again with this set of data: `@"H",@"$",@"$",@"*",@"L",@"L",@"O"` Hint: working doesn't mean it's correct

Comment: @XCool : ok got it.. thnx for that. adding i-- after removing the object wud cater to this prob. i hope that shud work perfectly. :)

Comment: After fixing the index bug this code is fine. **There's nothing wrong with modifying an array while iterating over it**, as long as the code does not use a fragile loop construct (fast enumeration, some enumeraturs, ...). This case with the for loop with a counter variable is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You use a NSPredicate for that:

Example:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"memberNumber == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:memberNumber]];
NSArray *matchingMembers = [members filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

Customer *customer = [matchingMembers lastObject];
NSLog(@"%@", customer.name);
```

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html) is the documentation link at Apple.

[Here](http://www.peterfriese.de/using-nspredicate-to-filter-data/) is another explanation

Answer (score -1):

You need regex that matches special characters, this link may help you.

your regex is somthing like this "[^[A-Za-z][0-9]]"

[How to get matches in iOS using regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184845/how-to-get-matches-in-ios-using-regular-expression)