# Getting two dates as substrings and store them in separate strings

Tags: ios, nsstring, uikit, nsdate

In my app I have a string - "contest will start from dd/mm/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy" I want both of the dates separately so I need a way to store these dates in two different strings.

Comment: sory I just wrote string wrong it is - "contest starts from dd/mm/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy"

Comment: Why would you store them in *strings* at all? Why wouldn't you store them in NSDate values or whatever the appropriate type is?

Comment: As @JonSkeet notes, your question does not really make sense. You can store your data in whatever you want to - well, at least you can try. What exactly is your problem and why does, whatever you tried to do not work?

Comment: I am making an app for APNS and I will give this message through notifying server and then on receiving that message I want my app to load a view if current date is between these two dates. Now I think you have got me..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a regular expression (semi-blatantly adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591743/937822)).

```
NSString *string                = @"contest will start from 10/11/2012 to 12/11/2012";

NSRegularExpression *regex      = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"from (.*) to (.*)"
                                                                            options:0
                                                                              error:NULL];
NSTextCheckingResult *results   = [regex firstMatchInString:string
                                                    options:0
                                                      range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
NSString *date1                 = [string substringWithRange:[results rangeAtIndex:1]];
NSString *date2                 = [string substringWithRange:[results rangeAtIndex:2]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *dateString = @"contest will start from dd/mm/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy";
NSArray *components = [dateString componentsSeparatedByString:@"to"];

NSString *firstDate = [[components objectAtIndex:0] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"contest will start from "];
NSString *secondDate = [[components objectAtIndex:1] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" "];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    unsigned units = NSYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit |  NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:units fromDate: date];

NSInteger year = [components year];
NSInteger month = [components month];
NSInteger day = [components day];

NSString *together = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i - %i - %i", day, month, year];
```

Comment: I think that he wants to go the other way...  From the long string to only the two dates as strings.

Comment: @Inafziger Really? That seems kind of a strange question then... he should just store dates into NSDates!

Comment: It says that he is *starting* with the string and needs to split the dates out.