# NSURL equal to server URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I'm getting url from my server. I used this code

`self.bookURL = [aDictionary objectForKey:@"bookurl"];`

The url is http://www.test.com/url. If this URL matches, I need to display a UIButton. How can I match this URL with `self.bookURL`? I used below `NSLog`, nothing displays in the log.

```
NSLog(@"book url is %@",bookURL);
NSString *thumburl=@"http://www.test.com/ur";
if(bookURL==thumburl){

}
```

Comment: Where is this `NSLog` statement?

Comment: And you can't compare the value of two objects using `==`. You need to use the `isEqual:` method.

Comment: if bookURL is not displayed in log,try to log `aDictionary` and see whether you are getting this url from server

Comment: also for string comparing, check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6591743/797901

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot compare strings (or objects for that matter) with `==`.

You can either convert the NSString to an NSURL and compare like this:

```
NSURL *thumburl = [NSURL URLFromString:@"http://www.test.com/ur"];

if ([self.bookURL isEqual:thumburl]){
     //do something
}
```

This assumes that the value `bookurl` stored in the NSDictionary is an object of type `NSURL`. If you want to do a string comparison between two NSStrings (instead of working with NSURL), then you can do the following:

```
if ([self.bookURL isEqualToString:thumburl]){
     //do something
}
```

This second example assumes that the self.bookURL object that you are getting back is NSString instead of NSURL.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare URLs using 
You can convert thumburl into an NSURL using

```
NSURL thumburl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com/ur"];
```

and then compare the two NSURLs using

```
if([self.bookURL isEqual: thumburl]){
    //They match
}
```

If they are both strings use

```
if([self.bookURL isEqualToString:thumbURL]){
    //They match
}
```

If nothing is displaying in the log the dictionary is probably returning an empty string, check this by logging (or better yet put a break point on the line after your dictionary gets populated)

Comment: Its also worth mentioning that in general when comparing objects for equality you should not use `==`. `==` is a very shallow equality check. In fact in this case merely checks if both objects occupy the same memory address, nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a simple string compare convert with

`[someURL absoluteString]`

For more complicated cases that arise with URLs check the method provided here...
https://stackoverflow.com/a/12332091/1381053